# How to filter TIFF images (mosaic/pyramid) in GeoServer?

Tags: geoserver

I have total 7000 TIFF images that I want to display on application in OpenLayers. I didn't want to create 7000 stores so I created mosaic and hosted it. But how can I filter TIFF images based on extent? I don't have any time or elevation data attached to TIFF image.

Can you also suggest any other approach to tackle this problem? (Hosting 7000 images and displaying them based on filtering either by bbox or anything else.)

Comment: please expand on what you mean by filter by bbox. this is the default behaviour for a WMS in openlayers.

Comment: @IanTurton yes like we do to normal layer in WMS or WFS (CQL_filter=bbox(the geom, extent)) like that

Comment: any wms request is limited to the BBOX specified in the request, there is no need for a 2nd filter. WFS requests on a raster layer make no sense

Comment: by doing that, we are only changing the extent of "what to show in the beginning" , if I zoom out, I can still see other tiffs

Comment: I want to show only specific area in in complete tiff, that falls inside extent and hide remaining tiff